# Hadoop Pig Latin regex match

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I have the following Pig Latin filter:

```
filtered = FILTER raw BY year >= 1960 AND string MATCHES '(?!.*[0-9].*|.{1}|.*@.*|.*www.*|.*http.*)';
```

I was intending to get the following results for the following strings:

```
a #false .{1}
email@example.com #false .*@.*
http://somesite.com #false .*http.*
www.somesite.com #false .*www.*
12word #false .*[0-9].*
wo12rd #false .*[0-9].*
word12 #false .*[0-9].*
red #true
```

Instead, I get an empty result set.

EDIT:
I've updated the regex to:

```
'^(?!.*[0-9].*|.{1}|.*@.*|.*www.*|.*http.*)$'
```

after m.buettner's correction, but continue to get an empty result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems. Firstly it seems like Pig Latin requires you to match the full string instead of "just a match somewhere within the string". But you negative lookahead does not consume any characters, so it does not match the full the string. This could simply be resolved by appending `.*`. Secondly your rule `.{1}` (where `{1}` is redundant) does not require this one character to be the only character in the string. So in your last example, it will simply consume the `r` of `red` and set off the negative lookahead.

Thus, here is the solution:

```
(?!.*[0-9]|.$|.*@|.*www|.*http).*
```

Comment: I continue to get an empty result set with the regex '^(?!.*[0-9].*|.{1}|.*@.*|.*www.*|.*http.*)$'. Thank you for correcting my regex - I have learnt! But my problem is not solved. The docs say that Pig Latin expects the Java regex format. I've read through the docs but I am obviously missing a crucial point.

Comment: @waigani Have you tried my first suggestion? (simply removing the `(?!` and `)`? These regexes are correct Java-regexes, but the question is whether they use the 'matches' function (which implies that the full string has to be matched) or not.

Comment: If I remove (?! and ) it would include every match though. I need to exclude every match.

Comment: Ah right. How does this work: `(?!.*[0-9].*|.$|.*@.*|.*www.*|.*http.*).*`?

Comment: '^(?!.*[0-9].*|.{1}|.*@.*|.*www.*|.*http.*)$' matched everything, not sure why. But removing ^ and $ and changing .{1} to .$ works as expected. So your last suggestion, minus the ^ looks like it will work - just running the map reduce now.

Comment: @waigani, right. I made one last edit to my answer with some explanation why this is the working answer (I felt like I needed to justify getting the checkmark :D)

Comment: @ waigani ummmm. actually, yes :D